# Excel - Compare two columns, if match then subtract the matched data and give the result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to subtract the rows from by matching column 1 and column 2. The values of the rows are present in characters.

the result should look like below:

[image: result after substraction]

So how should I do this process? I tried using match, lookup and combining them with substract but unsuccessful. am I missing some logic?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you show us what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your first example is backwards. For the others, use

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or, as per the OP's data table

In    C2, formula copied own :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(B2)>0,A2,B2),IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(B2)<0,A2,B2),"")
```